# Wine installation fails because of 32 and 64 bit packages uninstalling each other

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies, 64-bit, 32-bit

I am currently trying to install `wine` in Ubuntu 22.04 and it comes down to this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgphoto2-6:i386 : Depends: libgd3:i386 (>= 2.1.0~alpha~) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I then tried to manually add both of these packages and installing works but then when installing `wine` it gives the same error for the 64 bit versions (without: i386) and when installing those it goes back to the original error so they remove each other.

Comment: try this: `sudo apt install libgd3:i386` .. that may replace some *gd3 libraries, careful; then:
`sudo apt install wine32` .. which also installs a lot, but works fine in the end, for 32bit